# Google Cloud Container Optimized OS host logs to stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

**TL;DR**
What is the best practice to send container optimized os **host** logs (ssh and executed shell commands) to Stackdriver?

**Background:**
I'm using Googles Container Optimized OS which works great. It's super easy to send the container logs to Stackdriver, but how do I send **host** logs to Stackdriver?

It's for auditing purposes, I need to log all SSH connections (accepted or denied) and all commands executed via shell. Previously I would simply send the rsyslogd (auth,authpriv) to stackdriver via the stackdriver host logger package.

This is for Container Optimized OS VM:s running in a managed instance group (mig), not in Google Kubernetes Engine.

It might be super obvious, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: did you ever get a solution on this? I have the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On high level, that is what you need to do for any GCP COS instance to ship the OS audit logs to Google stackdriver:

First, you need to enable audit logs on COS using the following command:
  systemctl start cloud-audit-setup
That would allow the audit logs to generated and captured in the compute instance journal, you can use **journalctl** command to see the outcome

Second, you need to have Google Stackdriver agent installed on the instance and configured to ship audit logs from instance journal to stack driver. This can be achieved by having a docker container running fluentd-gcp google container image.

I am sharing the below cloud-init to do the whole job for you. All what you need to do is to have an instance metadata with key "user-data" and value is the below script:

```
#cloud-config
users:
- name: logger
  uid: 2001
  groups: docker

write_files:

- path: /etc/google-fluentd/fluentd.conf
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    # This config comes from a heavily trimmed version of the
    # container-engine-customize-fluentd project. The upstream config is here:
    # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-customize-fluentd/blob/6a46d72b29f3d8e8e495713bc3382ce28caf744e/kubernetes/fluentd- 
configmap.yaml
    <source>
        type systemd
        path /var/log/journal
        pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald.pos
        filters [{ "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "audit" }]  
        tag node-journal
        read_from_head true
    </source>
    <match **>
      @type copy
       <store>
        @type google_cloud
        # Set the buffer type to file to improve the reliability
        # and reduce the memory consumption
        buffer_type file
        buffer_path /var/log/google-fluentd/cos-system.buffer
        # Set queue_full action to block because we want to pause gracefully
        # in case of the off-the-limits load instead of throwing an exception
        buffer_queue_full_action block
        # Set the chunk limit conservatively to avoid exceeding the GCL limit
        # of 10MiB per write request.
        buffer_chunk_limit 2M
        # Cap the combined memory usage of this buffer and the one below to
        # 2MiB/chunk * (6 + 2) chunks = 16 MiB
        buffer_queue_limit 6
        # Never wait more than 5 seconds before flushing logs in the non-error
        # case.
        flush_interval 5s
        # Never wait longer than 30 seconds between retries.
        max_retry_wait 30
        # Disable the limit on the number of retries (retry forever).
        disable_retry_limit
        # Use multiple threads for processing.
        num_threads 2
      </store>
    </match>
- path: /etc/systemd/system/logger.service
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=logging docker container
    Requires=network-online.target
    After=network-online.target

    [Service]
    Environment="HOME=/home/logger"
    ExecStartPre=/usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh
    ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/google-fluentd/
    ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -fv logger
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm -u 0 \
       --name=logger \
       -v /var/log/:/var/log/ \
       -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers \
       -v /etc/google-fluentd/:/etc/fluent/config.d/ \
       --env='FLUENTD_ARGS=-q' \
       gcr.io/google-containers/fluentd-gcp:2.0.17
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=1
runcmd:
- systemctl daemon-reload
- systemctl start logger.service
- systemctl start cloud-audit-setup
```

Comment: I added the above cloud-config to the metadata of an instance running Container-Optimized OS v77, then restarted. It didn't seem to work, there is no `fluentd` running, not visible via `docker ps -a` nor `ps faux | grep fluent`.

Answer (score 3):

> how do I send host logs to Stackdriver?

[Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/ecb29ae43263328ec1d39aa3a2982925c6b154da/overlay-lakitu/app-admin/stackdriver/files/stackdriver-logging.service) are some code where COS packaged a Stackdriver Logging agent. You can start it via `sudo systemctl start stackdriver-logging`.

Comment: Is the Dockerfile for `gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:0.2-1.5.33-1-1` closed source?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Team answered:

> To have journald logs in stackdriver, you will need to configure
>   Fluentd to do so. See [these lines](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d388b3eea7620b4ea41b6f75fca40758b989fc69/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-configmap.yaml#L258-L310) of fluentd configmap for some
>   examples. Note that the "node-journal" filter in the configmap is not
>   enabled by default on GKE.
>
> To have audits on COS nodes, additionally, you will need to enable COS
>   audit logging system service. On COS nodes: Run "systemctl start
>   cloud-audit-setup". Then you will have audit logs like SSH login in
>   the journald log.